# how to use the first cell with specific value in my code

Tags: python, xlrd

With my Python code I'm looking for a cell with a specific table name, in this case 'Quality distribution'. In the Excel file there are two tables with this name and I only want to work with the first table.

My code is working correctly if there is only one cell with the specific table name, but now my code is finding the first cell with 'Quality distribution' and then goes looking for a second cell and starts the index at the second table. How can I adjust my code so that I work with the first table?

My Excel file contains out of 12 tables in columns A and B, and every table has 67 to 350 rows. Above the table a table name is stated.

An example (I have deletes some tables and rows for for the sheet has 2000 rows):

Summary
Creation date:  Fri Aug 02 13:49:15 CEST 2019
Generated by:   XXXX
Software:   CLC Genomics Workbench 12.0
Based upon: 1 data set
XXXXXXX_S7_L001_R1_001 (paired):    5.102.482 sequences in pairs
Total sequences in data set 5.102.482 sequences
Total nucleotides in data set   558.462.117 nucleotides

Quality distribution
average PHRED score % sequences:
0   0
1   0
27  0.889841454
28  1.157475911
29  1.472773446

Per-base analysis
Coverage
base position   % coverage:
0   100
1   100
2   100
147 37.30090572
148 36.1365508
149 33.95743483
150 24.3650639
151 0

Quality distribution
base position   PHRED score: 5%ile  PHRED score: 25%ile PHRED score: Median PHRED score: 75%ile PHRED score: 95%ile
0   0   0   0   0   0
1   18  32  32  33  34
2   18  32  33  33  34
3   18  32  33  34  34
146 15  37  38  39  39
147 15  37  38  39  39
148 15  37  38  39  39
149 15  37  38  39  39
150 15  36  38  39  39
151 13  33  37  38  39

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import xlrd

kit = ('test_QC_150.xlsx')

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(kit)

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

def phred_score():

    for sheet in wb.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                # searching for the quality distribution
                if cell.value == "Quality distribution":
                    index_quality_distribution = rowidx
                    print('index_quality_distribution: ', index_quality_distribution)


    index = index_quality_distribution + 35
    index_end = index_quality_distribution + 67

    print(index)
    print(index_end)

def main():
    phred_score()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is quite simple. Your code is not "wrong", you just haven't thought it through to the end:

Your for-loop runs through all the cells in the range you specified and you previously only had one cell that validated the if statement that follows:

```
for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                # searching for the quality distribution
                if cell.value == "Quality distribution":
                    index_quality_distribution = rowidx
```

now that there are two instances, it will find both, but since you are overwriting the "index_quality_distribution" variable, only the last one it finds will be kept "in memory". What you can do is wrap everything in a while-loop and break out of it when the index is found the first time:

```
while True:
   for sheet in wb.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                # searching for the quality distribution
                if cell.value == "Quality distribution":
                    index_quality_distribution = rowidx
                    print('index_quality_distribution: ', index_quality_distribution)
                    break #Exits the while-loop and stop iterating
   break #failsafe in case no "Quality distribution is found
```

That should do it.